# Como instalar pygame con pip

Tags: python, windows, pygame

He intentado instalar pygame con pip pero me sale esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que versión de python tienes?

Comment: @Christian Tengo la versión 3.11.1

Comment: No es recomendable trabajar con las últimas versiones ya que siempre va haber demoras para que los módulos puedan adaptarse s la nueva versión. Te recomiendo trabajar con una versión anterior o una donde pygame tenga soporte

Comment: Gracias, ja funciona